# Issue implementing snackbar in android app

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I'm working on an android app while learning to code in Java and I'm building a note taking app currently and am trying to convert what used to be a toast message to a snackbar message.  Below is what I currently have along with the toast message that used to be there that is now commented out.  I'm getting stuck on the method it says to call, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private void deleteNote() {
        getContentResolver().delete(NotesProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                noteFilter, null);
        Snackbar.make(this, getString(R.string.note_deleted), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.note_deleted),
//                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
```

The error android studio gives me is it cannot resolve the method "make".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The make function takes a view as the first parameter.

```
public static Snackbar make(View view, int resId, int duration)
```

If you need it in the bottom of your activity pass `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` as the first parameter.

Comment: That worked!  Marking as correct answer, but I had another question!  I need to add it to my  main activity now but it's giving me another weird error that hopefully you can help with.

I had to put on pastebin as the comment wouldn't let me do formatting.  http://pastebin.com/0iSpYEZA

It tells me an expression was expected where I put MainActivity for the view in snackbar.

Comment: `Snackbar.make(MainActivity, getString(R.string.all_deleted), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);` This is not right

Comment: What would I add for the view instead of MainActivity?  Or is the whole thing not right?

Comment: like mentioned on the answer `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`